# Custom JS files conflicting with eachother

Tags: javascript, drupal

Not exactly sure how to describe this properly, but I have a feeling that my two (custom) JS files are conflicting. When I enable them both, only one of them works. If I enable them seperatly, they work perfectly.

These are the files (wrapped in Drupal JS)

The first one makes sure my navbar (a vertical navbar at the left of the screen) can be scrolled on screens smaller than the navbar, but it will become fixed if the page is longer than the navbar.

```
    /**
 * @file
 * A JavaScript file for the theme.
 *
 * In order for this JavaScript to be loaded on pages, see the instructions in
 * the README.txt next to this file.
 */

// JavaScript should be made compatible with libraries other than jQuery by
// wrapping it with an "anonymous closure". See:
// - https://drupal.org/node/1446420
// - http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth
(function ($, Drupal, window, document, undefined) {


// To understand behaviors, see https://drupal.org/node/756722#behaviors
Drupal.behaviors.my_custom_behavior = {
  attach: function(context, settings) {

  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
      var navHeight = $('#left-bar').height() + 60;
      var windowHeight = jQuery( window ).height();
      var currentPosition = $('body').scrollTop();
      console.log(currentPosition + ' ' + (navHeight - windowHeight));
      if (currentPosition > (navHeight - windowHeight) - 1) {
        $('#left-bar').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': (windowHeight - navHeight)});
      } else {
        $('#left-bar').css({'position': 'relative', 'top': 0});
      }
    });

  });


  }
};


})(jQuery, Drupal, this, this.document);
```

The second one makes a certain div appear and fade out in random places on my page.

```
/**
 * @file
 * A JavaScript file for the theme.
 *
 * In order for this JavaScript to be loaded on pages, see the instructions in
 * the README.txt next to this file.
 */

// JavaScript should be made compatible with libraries other than jQuery by
// wrapping it with an "anonymous closure". See:
// - https://drupal.org/node/1446420
// - http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth
(function ($, Drupal, window, document, undefined) {


// To understand behaviors, see https://drupal.org/node/756722#behaviors
Drupal.behaviors.my_custom_behavior = {
  attach: function(context, settings) {

  $( document ).ready(function() { 
    showRandomQuote();
    setInterval(swapQuotes, 5500);
  });

  function showRandomQuote() {
    var numItems = $('.running-quote').length;
    var randomNumber = randomNumberFromRange(0, numItems-1);
    var quoteToDisplay = $( ".running-quote:eq(" + randomNumber + ")" );
    quoteToDisplay.addClass('displayed-quote');
    randomPlacement(quoteToDisplay);
    quoteToDisplay.fadeIn(800);
  }

  function swapQuotes() {
    var quoteToHide = $('.displayed-quote');
    quoteToHide.removeClass('displayed-quote');
    quoteToHide.fadeOut(800, showRandomQuote);
  }

  function randomPlacement(element) {
    var parent = element.parent().parent().parent();
    var parentWidth = parent.width();
    var parentHeight = parent.height();
    var randomWidth = randomNumberFromRange(200, 500);
    var randomXPos = randomNumberFromRange(0, parentWidth - randomWidth - 80);
    var randomYPos = randomNumberFromRange(0, parentHeight - element.height() - 60);
    element.width(randomWidth);
    element.css({"top": randomYPos, "left": randomXPos});
  }

  function randomNumberFromRange(min,max) {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
    return randomNumber;
  }

  }
};


})(jQuery, Drupal, this, this.document);
```

I have absolutely no clue what would cause one of them to break the other one.
Any clues?

Comment: One clue: both of them set the exact same property of `Drupal.behaviors`. The `Drupal.behaviors` object can have only one property named "my_custom_behavior", so the second one overwrites the first.

Comment: Well, that totally fixed it :)

Comment: The reason my JS was in 2 separate files though, was that a simple scroll event would not register, any way I tried. When I created a second file, the scroll event worked perfectly. Now I put them back together, it appears to register correctly now. 
Thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 0):

As @Pointy stated, your behaviors must have unique names.

**General code review:**

- your use of `$( document ).ready(function() {`, from the
  [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/756722), the attach
  function behaviors is called each time an element is refresh (either
  by page load or ajax), so you do not need to use jQuery.ready
  function.
- `showRandomQuote` should be inlined

Comment: Thanks!
What exactly do you mean with "showRandomQuote should be inlined" though?

Comment: There's no point in defining this function, so you can put its content directly

Comment: I did this purely for code cleanliness, why is this frowed down upon?

Comment: It is not frowned upon :) Your code style is yours, my suggestions are purely subjective